# Como fazer um select pegar 8 linhas seguidas ou mais onde há valores em comum?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela `coordenada` que possui as colunas `codigo, latitude, longitude, data` e gostaria de dar um `select` que selecionasse somente se possuir 8 linhas seguidas ou mais onde latitude **e** longitude são iguais à linha anterior.

A coluna `codigo` é um `auto_increment` e a coluna `data` está por ordem de inserção, assim como `codigo`.

Exemplo:

```
Linha 1: latitude = -30, longitude = -60
Linha 2: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 3: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 4: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 5: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 6: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 7: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 8: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 9: latitude = -29, longitude = -61
Linha 10:, latitude = -30, longitude = -60
```

Entre 2 e 9 há 8 linhas iguais ou mais, então pega as linhas.

Alguém sabe essa? Uso MySQL e PHPMyAdmin no XAMPP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Eis a solução completa:

A *query* a seguir foi fruto de uma série de considerações, e atende aos seguintes requisitos:

- Retorna resultados ordenados pelo campo `codigo`
- não agrupa resultados repetidos de sequências diferentes, ou seja: se uma sequência for interrompida, mesmo que a mesma coordenada volte a aparecer no futuro, será considerada uma nova sequência;
- retorna apenas as sequências que contém 8 ou mais coordenadas repetidas e em sequência ;
- retorna todas as linhas que contém as coordenadas que atendem ao requisito, e não apenas o resumo agrupado.

Esta é a *query* pronta:

```
SELECT * FROM coordenada AS r3 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
      codigo_a,
      MAX(codigo) AS codigo_b
   FROM (
      SELECT
         codigo,
         @combinado:=CONCAT(latitude,'x',longitude),
         @reinicio := ( @combinado != @anterior) AS reinicio,
         @anterior := @combinado AS anterior,
         @contagem := IF(@reinicio, 1, @contagem+1 ) AS contagem,
         @codigo_a := IF(@reinicio, codigo, @codigo_a) AS codigo_a,
         `data`
      FROM coordenada
      ORDER BY codigo
   ) AS r1
   WHERE contagem >= 8
   GROUP BY codigo_a
) AS r2
ON r3.codigo >= codigo_a AND r3.codigo <= codigo_b
ORDER BY codigo
```

## Explicação detalhada:

### Parte 1

Vamos começar pelo *select* mais interno (r3):

```
SELECT
   codigo,
   @combinado:=CONCAT(latitude,'x',longitude),
   @reinicio := ( @combinado != @anterior) AS reinicio,
   @anterior := @combinado AS anterior,
   @contagem := IF(@reinicio, 1, @contagem+1 ) AS contagem,
   @codigo_a := IF(@reinicio, codigo, @codigo_a) AS codigo_a,
   `data`
FROM coordenada
ORDER BY codigo
```

A lógica é a seguinte:

1. Este *select* faz uma passada inicial nos dados, e começamos criando uma *variável de usuário* no formato "lat x long", para facilitar os testes das condições seguintes.
2. Em seguida, criamos a flag `@reinicio`, que é setada caso a coordenada da linha atual seja diferente da coordenada da linha anterior (ou seja, começo de uma nova sequência).
3. Caso sejam diferentes, reiniciamos a `@contagem` à partir do número 1. Caso sejam iguais, incrementamos o valor da contagem.
4. Caso seja, uma nova sequência, armazenamos o `codigo` inicial dessa sequência em `@codigo_a`. Caso estejamos na mesma sequência, carregamos adiante o `@codigo_a`, mantendo seu valor. Em outras palavras, o `@codigo_a` vai sempre manter o código **inicial** da sequência em que estamos, em todas as linhas desta sequência.

O resultado vai ser parecido com isto:

<sub>tabela 1</sub>

```
Codigo, Combinado, Reinicio, Contagem, Codigo A
     1, '-12x-63',        1,        1,        1
     2, '-29x-63',        1,        1,        2
     3, '-29x-63',        0,        2,        2
     4, '-29x-63',        0,        3,        2
     5, '-29x-63',        0,        4,        2
     6, '-29x-63',        0,        5,        2
     7, '-29x-63',        0,        6,        2
     8, '-29x-63',        0,        7,        2
     9, '-29x-63',        0,        8,        2
    10, '-29x-63',        0,        9,        2
    11, '-29x-63',        0,       10,        2
    12, '-29x-63',        0,       11,        2
    13, '-29x-63',        0,       12,        2
    14, '-40x32' ,        1,        1,       14
    15, '-29x-63',        1,        1,       15
    16, '-29x-63',        0,        2,       15
    17, '-29x-63',        0,        3,       15                        
    18, '-29x-63',        0,        4,       15                        
    19, '-29x-63',        0,        5,       15                        
    20, '-29x-63',        0,        6,       15                        
    21, '-29x-63',        0,        7,       15                        
    22, '-29x-63',        0,        8,       15                        
    23, '-29x-63',        0,        9,       15                        
    24, '-29x-63',        0,       10,       15                        
    25 .....
```

Notar o seguinte: toda vez que a coordenada muda, dispara nossa flag `@reinicio` (ocorreu nos códigos 1, 2, 14 e 15 do exemplo). Consequentemente, a `@contagem` nessas linhas reiniciou do 1, e foi aumentando, até o próximo reinício. O `@codigo_a`, por sua vez, foi guardando o código inicial daquela sequência, em todas as linhas. No passo seguinte, veremos os motivos de o `@codigo_a` existir.

> A fonte destes dados não é a mesma da pergunta, usei um set maior e com mais variação, porém sem números decimais, para facilitar a leitura.

<sub>Uma possível alternativa a essa técnica seria em vez de criar o codigo_a, transformar a flag de reinício em um contador, que incrementaria a cada nova sequência. Fazendo uma comparação básica entre as duas possibilidades, ambas me parecem equiparáveis em complexidade.</sub>

### Parte 2

O nosso select intermediário é este (r2):

```
SELECT
   codigo_a,
   MAX(codigo) AS codigo_b
FROM (
   ... query 1 ...
) AS r1
   WHERE contagem >= 8
   GROUP BY codigo_a
```

A função deste *select* é organizar o nosso resultado anterior em algo usável para nosso select mais externo, fazendo o seguinte:

1. Começamos fazendo um "*select* do *select*", com o fim de agrupar os resultados anteriores em apenas uma linha por sequência de coordenadas iguais.

2. Utilizamos a clausula WHERE para selecionar para agrupamento somente as sequências cuja `@contagem` do passo anterior seja igual ou superior a 8, o que reduz nossos dados anteriores ao seguinte:

<sub>tabela 2</sub>

```
Codigo B, Combinado, Reinicio, Contagem, Codigo A
       9, '-29x-63',        0,        8,        2
      10, '-29x-63',        0,        9,        2
      11, '-29x-63',        0,       10,        2
      12, '-29x-63',        0,       11,        2
      13, '-29x-63',        0,       12,        2
      22, '-29x-63',        0,        8,       15                        
      23, '-29x-63',        0,        9,       15                        
      24, '-29x-63',        0,       10,       15                        
      25...
```

3. Porém, como agrupamos com `GROUP BY codigo_a`, será retornada apenas UMA linha de cada sequência (e graças ao passo 2, essa sequência será com certeza de 8 ou mais coordenadas).

4.  Mas qual das linhas desta sequência queremos? Como o `@codigo_a` vai conter sempre o **início** de cada sequência, precisamos da linha que contém **o maior** código da referida sequência, que é o que define onde ela termina. É exatamente isso que faz o `MAX(codigo)`, e para facilitar a leitura, nós o chamamos de `codigo_b`. O resultado final deste select é:

<sub>tabela 3</sub>

```
Codigo B, Combinado, Reinicio, Contagem, Codigo A
      13, '-29x-63',        0,       12,        2
      24, '-29x-63',        0,       10,       15                        
      ... sequencias seguintes ...
```

Conclusão desta etapa: A primeira sequência vai do código 2 (extraído do `codigo_a`) ao código 13 (extraido do `codigo_b`), a segunda vai do código 15 ao código 24 e assim sucessivamente. Conseguimos com isso, então, uma linha para cada sequência que nos interessa. Cada linha dessas define o código de início e o de fim da respectiva sequência.

### Passo 3 e final

Como nós não queremos só os agrupamentos, e sim todos os dados de cada linha, vem o terceiro *select* (r3) que cruza todas as coordenadas com a espécie de "indice remissivo" que criamos no passo 2.

```
SELECT * FROM coordenada AS r3 INNER JOIN (
   ... query 2 ...
) AS r2
ON r3.codigo >= codigo_a AND r3.codigo <= codigo_b
ORDER BY codigo
```

Este select é simplesmente o seguinte:

1. Começamos com um *select* tradicional, pegando todos os dados de cada coordenada com `*`.
2. Para cruzar estes dados com o que obtivemos na tabela 3 (select r2), vamos usar um **[inner join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)**, cuja condição é simplesmente esta: para cada sequência listada no passo anterior, queremos todos os resultados cujo código esteja entre `codigo_a` e `codigo_b` (inclusive).
3. Finalmente, ordenamos por `codigo`, para manter a consistência com o resto que fizemos até agora.

> IMPORTANTE: Para que esta query funcione por mais de uma vez, é fundamental antes executar um `SET @anterior = '';` para reiniciar a nossa lógica do select mais interno, que usa variáveis de usuário.

<sub>Espero ter ajudado com o conteúdo. Quando li a pergunta, tive impressão que não daria para resolver apenas com MySQL, mas fiz questão de aprender um pouco mais sobre o DB para conseguir responder (e foi uma bela série de tentativas frustradas até chegar nisso).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Se as linhas são iguais, faça um `GROUP BY` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude
FROM tabela
GROUP BY CONCAT(latitude,longitude)
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(latitude,longitude)) > 7
```

Comment: Desta forma você não garante que as linhas iguais estão seguidas como solicitado na pergunta.

Comment: @Osvaldo acredito ser um erro de lógica, uma vez que os registos são exactamente iguais e se for preciso saber quantos registos existem, basta adicionar um count.

Comment: Veja que existe um campo codigo (auto-incremento) que diferencia cada linha e, pelo que diz o autor da pergunta, as linhas estão ordenadas por este codigo. Sua expressão SQL retorna todos que tiverem mais de sete repetições, independente das repetições estarem ou não em sequência. Se fosse no PostgreSQL a utilização de Window Function resolveria o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Este código é feio mas simples e funcional sob os dados passado como exemplo.
Utiliza variáveis para controlar a qtde de registros repetidos.

Não tentei variar os dados, mas acredito que deva atender sua necessidade , talvez com algumas adaptações...
(talvez primeiro gerar a subquery em temporaria e então fazer o group by / having sobre a temporaria para facilitar a recuperação das linhas com todos os detalhes, baseado na coluna "indice")

Para ver este exemplo no [SQL Fiddle, clica aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f6a7/1/2)

```
drop table if exists tst1; 

CREATE temporary TABLE tst1
    (`linha` int, `lat` int, `lng` int)
;

INSERT INTO tst1
    (`linha`, `lat`, `lng`)
VALUES
    (1, -30, -60),
    (2, -29, -61),
    (3, -29, -61),
    (4, -29, -61),
    (5, -29, -61),
    (6, -29, -61),
    (7, -29, -61),
    (8, -29, -61),
    (9, -29, -61),
    (10, -30, -60)
;

set @ant = 0;
set @x=0;

select lat, lng, max(indice), count(indice)
from (
select linha, lat, lng
     , @ant as ant
     , (case when lat != @ant then @x:=@x+1 else @x end ) as indice
     , (@ant := lat) as ignorar
from tst1 
) as x
group by 1,2
having count(indice) >= 8
;
```

O resultado final é:

```
lat lng max(indice) count(indice)
-29 -61 2   8
```