# Agrupamento MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query

Preciso agrupar uma consulta com um detalhe, o agrupamento deve ser feito somente quando a informação se repete em sequência, por exemplo:

```
id     nome
1      lucas
2      lucas
3      marcos
4      lucas
5      marcos
```

No exemplo acima, somente os "lucas" com ID's 1 e 2 poderão ser agrupadas, as demais informações não, pois não encontram-se em sequencia.

Segue trecho da query:

```
$SQL = "select * from clientes where id = '".$id."' group by nome order by id desc ";
$RSS = mysql_query($SQL, $conexao);
while($RS = mysql_fetch_array($RSS)){
  echo $RS["nome"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Você quer uma saída em php?

Comment: Isso mesmo, em PHP

Comment: Você poderia colocar na pergunta o trecho que busca essas informações?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: [Como fazer um select pegar 8 linhas seguidas ou mais onde há valores em comum?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10768/70)

Comment: Aparentemente esta solução resolveu, preciso realizar mais testes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar o GROUP BY do SQL, vamos fazer a junção dos nomes em sequência no código PHP.

Ficaria assim:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER BY id";
$RSS = mysql_query($SQL, $conexao);
while($RS = mysql_fetch_array($RSS)){
  if ($RS["nome"] != $nome_atual)
    echo $RS["nome"]."<br>";
  $nome_atual = $RS["nome"];
}
```

Sem a cláusula 'GROUP BY' do MySQL, os nomes virão na sequência informada. 
O 'if' verifica se o nome recebido do banco é diferente do anterior. Se for, ele publica.

Comment: Não acho que essa essa afirmativa O `if' verifica se o nome recebido do banco é diferente do anterior. Se for, ele publica` esteja correta. Primeiro que a query vai retornar UM E SOMENTE UM REGISTRO, registro esse cujo o id seja igual a variavel $id e vai imprimir na tela o nome correspondente a esse id porque não haverá nome anterior para fazer comparação. Portanto sua resposta foi aceita com 2 ups não se sabe porque!!

Comment: Tem razão, @LeoCaracciolo. Só tinha me preocupado com o código PHP de não repetir o nome. No SQL só tinha tirado o GROUP BY. Agora a consulta traz todos os registros e em ordem ascendente, de acordo com a pergunta. Agradeço pelo comentário.